# Creating coverage map in google maps using .tab file?

Tags: mapinfo, google-maps-api

I used MapInfo Professional 11.5 to convert a .tab file to .kml file of google maps.

However, the converted .kml file has a great size(80Mb), so i cannot use this .kml file in google maps.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really see a question but you could try to limit the number of records that you are converting or maybe limit the number of columns.